# Same template driven form for creating and editing data Angular4 example

Tags: angular5, angular4-forms

I want to edit form with existing object values. I can't do it because I haven't idea how to do that? I tried different technique two-way data binding but I not found any solution

Comment: Can you add the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reactive Forms

You can you use reactive forms.
First, import `Forms` and `Reactive Forms` to your `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
     ...
     FormsModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     ...
]
```

then in your component, use `FormBuilder` like this:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  this.initForm(firstname, lastName);
}

myForm: FormGroup;

initForm(firstname, lastName) {
       this.myForm = this.fb.group({
             first_name: [firstname, Validators.required],
             last_name: [lastName, Validators.required],
             nick_name: [null, Validators.required]
   });
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
     <input type="text" formControlName='first_name' />
     <input type="text" formControlName='last_name' />
     <input type="text" formControlName='nick_name' />
</form>
```

A useful tip here, is to print your form Values to see their changes:
to this for debugging purpose, add this to your template:

```
<pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
```